# Font size small after wordpress site migration

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I moved my site to a new server but the the font is displaying tiny on the new server. It was moved from a windows server to a linux server

if you brows down a bit on the home page you will notice the tiny font.

It is a setting on the server?

Im stumped, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: just remove the percentage on your font size. Sot sure why you would use that. You are better using `em`

Comment: There is lots you need to fix with the font sizing. I am just giving you a starting point. That font picks up font sizes from all over the place.

Comment: thanks, but it is just a site move, why do i have to now start fiddling with fonts.

The site is fine on the live site but not on the new location. why is this is actually what im trying to figure out. Fiddling with the css is not ideal

Comment: The new server you have lots of links on the page that are not TLS, so you're getting notices `Parts of this page are not secure (such as images)` and firefox is blocking this content.

Comment: If you remove the `font-size:32%` then it displays correctly (in paragraph text)

Comment: You'll actually notice that both sites load up the font in 'tiny' font as you put it, but the Windows server then changes the size. So I would imagine you should actually set the font size in your stylesheet, to stop it initially loading so small. Where is your CSS for the font size?

Comment: And it's probably because Windows as servers are just awful lol You shouldn't set fonts as percentage, because that implies there's a parent size to compare to.. when there generally isn't with fonts. Either use px, pt, or em as suggested. I generally use pt with fonts.

Comment: @Martin thanks that is what the problem was. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Lee I agree windows servers are terrible. Although I disagree about percentage font sizes, as `em` (and `rem`) also work from a *parent font size* basis the exact same way percentage does.

Comment: @RyanVdMerwe glad you found what it was. It looks like your testing server (new?) is a wyrd URI address so you're still referencing things from the original server (with the more useful domain name) which of course is not HTTPS. It won't help anyone for you to remove your website links, it means future readers now have no reference for exploring the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as per Martins comment The new server is on a secure server ("https://"). The problem is that some of the theme files were referenced directly and therefore were not loading because they were coming from an insecure ("http://") location.

There is obviously an underlying issue with the font that is css based that others pointed out, but this I can look at now that the site is working again.

appreciate the response from everyone!

Comment: Great that you've resolved it, but you shouldn't put comments like this as answers, or they'll get downvoted, or deleted. Best to add it as a comment under your question, or to edit your original question so it's easy to see it's been resolved.

Comment: I don't agree with that @Lee , as OP can mark his own answer as the correct answer and thus close the question, so in the future someone finds the question and then reads the answer that it was caused by HTTP and HTTPS mixed content communication.